# Upload file with AJAX is not working properly "Uncaught ReferenceError"

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, asynchronous, file-upload

This error appeared on the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadedCAPA is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (profile:521)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (afd.js:1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.m.handle (afd.js:1)
```

I want to send a POST request to `http://localhost/cakes/process.php` when I click on `$("#upload")`, but I'm getting this error `uploadedCAPA is not defined` why?

my code:

```
function showLoading() {
  document.getElementById('loading').style = 'visibility: visible';
}
function hideLoading() {
  document.getElementById('loading').style = 'visibility: hidden';
}
$('#upload').click(function() {
  //call show loading function here
  showLoading();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/cakes/process.php',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: {
      file: uploadedCAPA
    },
    success: function() {
      //call hide function here
      hideLoading();
      alert('Data has been Uploaded: ');
    },
    error: function(a) {
      //if an error occurs
      hideLoading();
      alert(
        'An error occured while uploading data.\n error code : ' + a.statusText
      );
    }
  });
});
```

html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="capaUpload" type="file" name="uploadedCAPA" />
  <button type="button" id="upload" name="sendImg">Upload</button>
</form>
```

php:

```
if (isset($_POST['sendImg'])) {
  move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['uploadedCAPA']['tmp_name'],
    'user/7c50b2fe-1003-11e9-a766-c89cdc4e9f5f/avatar/'.$_FILES['uploadedCAPA'][
      'name'
    ]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference a variable called `uploadedCAPA`, but never defined that variable anywhere.

If you just want to post the form contents, to include the file input, then I imagine you're looking for `FormData`.  Perhaps something like this:

```
let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost/cakes/process.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: formData,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     success: function () { /.../ },
     error: function () { /.../ }
})
```

The `contentType` and `processData` options are relevant here as well for uploading `multipart/form-data` with jQuery.  But basically the overall point is that you can't just use the name of the input element as a variable, you need to capture the data from the form and post that to the server.

You might also use something more specific than `document.querySelector('form')` to identify your form element.  Maybe give it an `id` and use `document.getElementById` instead.

Comment: i think it's not sending the data from my form https://pastebin.com/fDLdQ3Nr it's showing the `success` mensage, but it's not uploading the image, so i think it's not sending the correct data, could you tell me? My php code is working fine (without the ajax).

Comment: i tried to add `enctype: 'multipart/form-data',` to the ajax call, but nothing changed

Comment: @user236945896: When you debug, where specifically does it fail?  Does the AJAX call include the data for the image?  What is the server-side code doing?

Comment: it executes the alert on the function `success: function(status, result, request)` results: `status = undefined`, `result = undefined`, `request = OK`. The code from my php file is not being executed

Comment: @user236945896: *"The code from my php file is not being executed"* - Sounds like you need to debug that code then.  If the AJAX request is being successfully made but the server-side code isn't doing what you expect, start debugging that code.

Comment: I tested this code alone: https://pastebin.com/hxeW6GMk and it's working, but when i try to make a call to this code: https://pastebin.com/P2GgJQz7 with the ajax, it does not work. Maybe it's because when i use the Ajax i change `<input type="submit" ...>` to `<input type="button" ...>` ?

Comment: @user236945896: You're really going to have to be more investigative than "it's working" and "it does not work".  And don't assume the problem has anything to do with your button element unless you have found some specific evidence to suggest that.  Now would be a good time to start learning about debugging with PHP.

Comment: i searched about it, anyways how could i see the result of the debug from the php code if the php code only not work when i make a ajax call?

Comment: @user236945896: If you're using an IDE you can probably use its debugger.  Failing that, you can add all sorts of logging statements and/or debugging output in your PHP code.  The log output you can observe wherever you log that information, and output to the client can be observed in your browser's debugging tools.  Again, the goal here is to be more specific than "it doesn't work".  Anything could be going wrong.  Could be a typo that neither of us noticed, could be something unrelated to the code shown at all, could be anything.  Debugging is a critical skill to have.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above javascript compiler searches for variable named **uploadedCAPA**
 data: { file: uploadedCAPA } in this part which you have never defined either in global scope or as local variable.

if you want to upload files using javascript and jquery you have to first get all your files in the form of FormData Using method new FormData() provided by javascript to get all your files.

Like this

```
const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file',files);
```

and then in the ajax call data will be formData Like this data:formData in place of  data: { file: uploadedCAPA };